# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource [Twitter API]

Tags: angular, typescript, cors

I'm aware that this is one of the most common problem. But unfortunately after doing a lot of study about `CORS` from the internet and questions on stackoverflow I'm not able to solve it. I'm trying to create a simple Angular project with twitter API. I want to fetch all my timeline status on the webpage with the twitter-api. Here's my code:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const Twitter = require('twit');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

const api_client = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: 'mykey',
    consumer_secret: 'mykey',
    access_token: 'mykey',
    access_token_secret: 'mykey'
})

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.get('/home_timeline', (req, res) => {
    const params = { tweet_mode: 'extended', count: 10 };

    api_client
      .get('statuses/home_timeline', params)
      .then(timeline => {
        res.send(timeline);
      })
      .catch(error => {
      res.send(error);
    });
});
```

This is my service **twitterservice.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TwitterserviceService {

  api_url = 'https:/localhost:3000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTimeline() {
    return this.http
      .get<any[]>(this.api_url+'/home_timeline')
      .pipe(map(data => data));
  }
}
```

and this is the component which is using the service **twitter-timeline.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TwitterserviceService } from '../twitterservice.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-twitter-timeline',
  templateUrl: './twitter-timeline.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./twitter-timeline.component.scss']
})


export class TwitterTimelineComponent implements OnInit {

  myTimeline: any;

  constructor(private api: TwitterserviceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.getTwitterTimeline();
  }

  getTwitterTimeline(): void {
    this.api.getTimeline()
      .subscribe(
        myTimeline => {
          this.myTimeline = myTimeline;
          console.log(this.myTimeline);
        }
      )
   }  
}
```

On `Postman` I'm getting exactly what I want:

[image]

But the browser is telling a different story:

[image]

I tried disabling the security settings and I also added an extension `CORS everywhere` but I think that's not a good idea. I'm getting this for both Chrome and Firefox. Please correct me.

Please correct me where I'm wrong.

Comment: What's the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker, sorry for the late reply. (wifi had some issues). Status code is 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're making a https request in your angular app. Try using http://url in your service component instead.

Comment: This worked :-). But are you sure this is the preferred way. Because i don't think now it is secure. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: All I know about the difference between http and https is, that https provides a way to securely identify a client, in order to prevent man in the middle attacks. I have started reading about https, tls and ssl and this stuff, but I can't answer your question. Right now you're making a request from localhost to localhost. As long as you dont expose your node backend to the public internet, you should be save. Btw. I'd appreciate if you'd mark my answer as the solution to your question. :-) Also https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_intro.html if you'd like to read about https.

Comment: Ok I'll do some more research on https. And sorry for the delay in accepting answer. Actually stackoverflow doesn't allow immediate acceptance of an answer. Sometimes it takes time. :-)

Comment: But tomorrow I would like to deploy this project for public use. Then It will be a problem. Anyway, lets see. Will think about this :-)